# Outer Join with Window Functions T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wracking my brain trying to figure this out. I know there is a simple way to do this, probably using window functions with outer joins (or WHERE NOT IN statements), but I keep going in circles. I'm getting held up at the part where I need to break my data into sets. I did not initially design this database, so it is not normalized.

I have a "TemplateItems" table which represents a list of about 50 items. These items **should** be part of every project.

```
TemplateItem
-------------
    a
    b
    c
    d
    e      
    f
    g
```

My "Projects" table contains a list of projects, like this:

```
ProjectID | TemplateItem | PercentComplete
-------------------------------------------
Project1          a             100
Project1          b             100
Project1          c             100
Project1          d             100
Project1          e             100
Project2          a             100
Project2          c             100
Project2          e             100
```

I need to output results that find all missing TemplateItems in the Projects table, **by ProjectID**.
So the results would be this:

```
ProjectID | MissingTemplateItem 
-------------------------------
Project1            f            
Project1            g        
Project2            b         
Project2            d         
Project2            f         
Project2            g
```

I would appreciate any hints in the right direction here. It's grouping it by ProjectID and doing a comparison against the TemplateItems table that's throwing me here. I keep wanting to do an iterative loop, but I really feels that's not the right way to do it and I shouldn't kluge my way out of this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach.  Generate all possible combinations using `cross join`.  Then, filter out the ones that exist.  Here is one way:

```
select p.ProjectId, t.TemplateItem as MissingTemplateItem
from (select distinct ProjectId from TemplateItems) p cross join
     (select distinct TemplateItem from TemplateItems) t left join
     TemplateItems ti
     on ti.ProjectId = p.ProjectId and ti.Template_item = t.TemplateItems
where ti.ProjectId is null;
```

Comment: I had to change some syntax, since the TemplateItems table does not have ProjectIDs in it. It appears to work, but it is also selecting some items, seemingly randomly, that do exist in the Projects table. I am still trying to figure it out, and appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Comment: I understand your solution, and think it's a clever way to go about it. I would upvote you, but I don't have 15 rep yet, lol. I have put the `select distinct ProjectId from Projects p cross join (select distinct TemplateItem from TemplateItems) t` in a CTE, and am trying to do a SELECT ProjectID, TemplateItem FROM CTE WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TemplateItem, ProjectID FROM Projects)

Comment: I have this so far, but I think I just succeeded in re-writing your query, lol  

    `; with cte as (select p.projectid, t.TemplateItem from 
    (select     distinct projectid  from Projects)  p 
    cross join (select distinct TemplateItem from TemplateItems) t)
    
    select projectid, TemplateItem as missing from cte 
    except (select projectid, TemplateItem from Projects)
    order by projectid, TemplateItem`

Comment: @user3191188 . . . That would be a very similar approach.